# jQuery global context

Tags: jquery

Assuming the following html structure :

```
<div id="anId">
    <span id="1"> aSpan </span>
    <span id="2"> anotherSpan </span>
</div>
<span id="3"> anOutsideSpan </span>
```

Is there a way to define a "global context" for jQuery selectors? Something like:

```
$(IDoNotKnowWhatToDoHere). SomethingAboutContext; // Defining the context as div#anID

$('span').doSomething; // Action only on span#1 and span#2 and not on span#3

$('span#1').doSomethingElse;

$('span').doSomethingStrange;

$('span#2').doSomethingCool;

$(SomethingAboutRemovingGlobalContext); //Removing the context
```

That way i can avoid doing this :

```
$('div#anId span').doSomething; // Action only on span#1 and span#2 and not on span#3

$('div#anId span').doSomethingElse; // Same as last code comment

$('div#anId span#1').doSomethingStrange; // Same as last code comment

$('div#anId span#2').doSomethingCool; // Same as last code comment
```

There is only 4 actions here but the code i'm working on has something like 100.

I want to avoid always repeting the `div#anId`.

- Keep in mind it's an example, not actual code.
- My question is not about chaining.

Comment: You shouldn't set id to a digit. ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var $g = $.proxy($.fn.find, $("div"));
$g('span').doSomething; // Action only on span#1 and span#2 and not on span#3
$g('#1').doSomethingElse;
$g('span').doSomethingStrange;
$g('#2').doSomethingCool;
```

So what your doing here is your creating a new selector that delegates to `$("div").find` and using that for all your selecting.

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot chain the methods, store a reference to the selected elements. Selecting them over and over again is unnecessary (and slow):

```
var $elements = $('div#anId span');

$elements.doSomething();
$elements.doSomethingElse();
//...
```

**Update:** As IDs have to be unique, you don't have to provide any context to select a particular `span` element if it has an ID. `$('div#anId span#1').doSomethingStrange();` would just become `$('#1').doSomethingStrange();`.

You could also store a reference to the ancestor:

```
var $context = $('div#anId');
```

and use [`find()` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/find/):

```
$context.find('span').something();
```

But even then, you could use method chaining together with [`end()` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/end/):

```
$('div#anId')
  .find('span')
     .doSomething()
  .end()
  .find('.somethingElse')
      .doSomethingElse()
  .end()
  //...
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i didn't know about the "end()". :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the *same* actions for each `<span>`, regardless of which `<div>` they are in or following, you could do something like:

```
$('div span').doSomething(); // both spans inside a div
$('div span:first').doSomething(); // first span inside a div
$('div').next().doSomethingElse(); // span after div
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, jQuery supports that already:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/

You only have to pass the context element as a second parameter in the jQuery function call, in your case would be:

```
var context = $('div#anId');
$('span', context);
```

You could do `context.find('span')` also, and the result would be the same.

I haven't read the source code thoroughly yet to know which use has better performance, but my guess is that the difference wouldn't be too noticiable.

Answer (score -1):

Did you never learn about chaining?

```
$('div#anId span').doSomething().doSomethingElse().doSomethingStrange().doSomethingCool();
```

BTW a number is not a valid ID. It has to start with a letter. See: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-name

Comment: This is not the point, i know about chaining. My question is about context. It looks like you can solve the probleme by chaining but it's another problem I'm trying to solve.

Comment: @Mono: And what problem is that? Why can't you either chain the methods or store a reference to the elements?

Comment: @MonoNeurone I can't really help with your question if you don't say what it is. What is the other problem you are trying to solve?